# How to write a Discord music bot without FFmpeg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am writing a Discord music bot. No experience. I found a way on YouTube only through youtube _dl and FFmpeg. In this case, the bot first downloads video from YT in .mp3 format and only then broadcasts it to voice chat. How can I make the bot directly relay the video to the voice chat, rather than download it? Thank you in advance.

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile('song.mp3')

    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove('song.mp3')
            print('[log] Старый файл удалён')

    except PermissionError:
        print('[log] Не удалось удалить файл')

    await ctx.send('Пожалуйста, ожидайте')

    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192'
        }]
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        print('[log] Загружаю музыку...')
        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir('./'):
        if file.endswith('.mp3'):
            name = file
            print('[log] Переименовываю файл: {file}.')
            os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'), after=lambda e: print(
        f'[log] {name}, музыка закончила своё проигрывание.'))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.07

    song_name = name.rsplit('-', 2)
    await ctx.send(f'Сейчас проигрывается музыка: {song_name[0]}')
```

Comment: I have yet to see a music bot which is able to do that. I do not think it is impossible, but you will probably have to write a lot of interaction code with Discord yourself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is highly recommended to post your code as a text. Please, retrieve the most relevant parts of your program and add it to your question.

Comment: Lu M, But for the Vexera bot, everything starts almost instantly, and even starts live broadcasts, but my bot hangs (most likely it tries to download a video broadcast that is continuously running)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing music with a bot from Youtube without downloading the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688808/playing-music-with-a-bot-from-youtube-without-downloading-the-file)

Comment: Nah, it doesn't wok