# Alternate ways to play music on discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl

I am currently using youtube-dl along with ffmpeg to play songs from my discord bot. However, searching for the song, downloading the video and extracting the audio takes a long time.

So I wanted to know if there is any way to speed up the process so the music can be played almost instantaneously.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/vbe0201/ade9b80f2d3b64643d854938d40a0a2d) might help you.

Comment: Using ffmpeg and youtube-dl, you can avoid downloading songs, as explained in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688808/playing-music-with-a-bot-from-youtube-without-downloading-the-file/62114462#62114462)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Lavalink](https://github.com/Frederikam/Lavalink) then. You basically have to host a Lavalink server with your bot and it comes with logs which is really good. It handles sending the songs to discord.
https://github.com/Devoxin/Lavalink.py
You could use this as your wrapper for python